# Can I use php deployer for CI/CD in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to use Gitlab CI/CD and for running tests and deploying the code on the production server finally come up with the following `.gitlab.ci.yml`

The production server is a simple Ubuntu server

Is it a bad practice and how can I improve it?

```
stages:
  - testing
  - deploying

image: php:latest

services:
  - mysql:latest

variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: project_name
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret

cache:
  paths:
    - vendor/
    - node_modules/

before_script:
  - apt-get update -yqq
  - apt-get install gnupg -yqq
  - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
  - apt-get install git nodejs libcurl4-gnutls-dev libicu-dev libmcrypt-dev libvpx-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libxpm-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev libxml2-dev libexpat1-dev libbz2-dev libgmp3-dev libldap2-dev unixodbc-dev libpq-dev libsqlite3-dev libaspell-dev libsnmp-dev libpcre3-dev libtidy-dev libonig-dev libzip-dev -yqq
  - docker-php-ext-install mbstring pdo_mysql curl json intl gd xml zip bz2 opcache
  - pecl install xdebug
  - docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
  - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
  - php composer.phar install

  - cp .env.testing .env

  - php artisan key:generate
  - php artisan config:cache
  - php artisan migrate
  - php artisan db:seed
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

test:
  stage: testing
  script:
    - php vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never
deploy:
  stage: deploying
  script:
    - php artisan deploy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Consider building your custom docker image based on `php:latest`, which will contain all required dependencies inside (git nodejs ...) and use your custom image for your builds. It will save you some time per each build, and you get cleaner `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

(P.S. you can even host it inside GitLab Container Registry)

2) It is not recommended to use `latest` tag, because after it gets updated, your build might start failing even if you personally didn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a bad practice. but you can use bit advance tools like **jenkin**

https://www.jenkins.io